# Need help randomizing a list and posting it as a position on my form

Tags: vb.net, list, multidimensional-array, random

I'm a high school student trying to learn VB.Net programming. I've been trying to get a whack-a-mole game going. I have been trying to make a list of positions for a button, and somehow retrieving the integers and posting it as a position on my app. I've been experimenting with random number generators but I can't catch how to retrieve numbers off a list and exchanging them into positions.
Here's the code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim red, blue, green, yellow
    Dim ListX As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim ListY As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {400, 350})
    Private Sub btnstart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnstart.Click
        For pos = 1 To 7
            PictureBox3.Location = New Point(73, 398)
        Next pos
    End Sub
    Sub Main()
        Dim ListX As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim ListY As New List(Of Integer)(New Integer() {400, 350})
    End Sub
    Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click

    End Sub
```

Comment: a) Please read [ask] and take the [tour] b) a list of integers cant be used as a set of positions (Points) c) the ListX and ListY in `Main` are not the same as the ones declared in the form - research what `Dim` and `New` actually do d) turn on Option Strict e) I dont see anything to do with Random anything.

Comment: So you are trying to "catch how to retrieve numbers off a list and exchanging them into positions"? Very broad

Comment: when clicking on start button, the picture will appear on random place and when clicked on the picturebox, it will disappear and be shown in another place?

Comment: You didn't listen in class. You have to stop playing when the teacher talks. You are a student, you should have your notes and a book to make your project. there's only half your project type in. type the rest and show me some randomization done somewhere and I help you.

Comment: Bruh, the teacher doesnt teach, just takes attendance. Its basically a self taught class in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code I wrote:

```
Public Class Form37
Private Sub btnstart_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnstart.Click
    'set the location of picturebox randomly
    PictureBox3.Location = GetLocation()
End Sub

Private Function GetLocation() As Point
    'get a random value between 0 to 400 for x and 0 to 350 for y
    Dim x_ As Integer
    Dim y_ As Integer
    Randomize()
    x_ = CInt(Int((400 * Rnd()) + 1))
    y_ = CInt(Int((350 * Rnd()) + 1))

    'set those x and y as point
    Dim Loc As Point = New Point(x_, y_)

    'return location from this function
    Return Loc
End Function

Private Sub PictureBox3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox3.Click
    '// when cliked on picturebox,
    '// increase score or whatever you want to do 

    '// show the picturebox in another place now 
    PictureBox3.Location = GetLocation()

End Sub
End Class
```

**Explanation**:
On clicking the button, the `picturebox3` will relocate to a random point in the form.
On clicking the `picturebox3`, you can do coding where you can increase score or whatever and then the picturebox will again relocate to another random point.

Hope this helps

Comment: Haha sorry, i was wondering if there is a way to randomize two arraylists and make the output of the two lists the next position.

Comment: of course you can do that. just get a random number between 0 to the numbers of items in  listbox1 and set it as index and get the value from the listbox as X, do the same for Y. then do what I did in the above code to set those integers as point

Comment: no problem bro. dont forget to mark the answer if you got the help so people can know it's already answered haha

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 1):

Subaz's code simplified:

```
 Private Function GetLocation() As Point
    Dim rn As New Random
    Return New Point(rn.Next(400), rn.Next(350))
End Function
```

Comment: i just made it longer so the OP can know what's happening exactly haha but nice +1